# Windows 10 Universal App custom map

Tags: geolocation, maps, windows-10, win-universal-app

I want to create an app for airplane navigation. Since for pilots the Bing maps are useless I need to create my own map a texture of an aeronautical map.

I couldn't find any clue how to start on this. Is there an SDK for Bing maps where I can create my own texture/overlay?
Do I need to start from rock bottom and create a picture and change its position so the relevant part is in the visible area of the device?

I need the following features:

- Show current position on the map.
- Add some custom POIs via coordinates

Comment: making a quick search I found you could add your won layers to the Bing Maps control. Have no idea how easy/hard that could be https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh846488.aspx https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/ve_layer.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After quite some research I figured it out myself.
Here is most of the code needed if you have the same scenario

Uri format:
`"https://webserver/tiles/{zoomlevel}/{x}/{y}.png";`

```
private void InitMap()
    {
        _gps = new Geolocator();
        pointBuffer = cologne;
        image = RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/images/airplane.png"));
        MyMap.Style = MapStyle.None;

        //Setup Icao Layer
        _icaoTileSource = new MapTileSource();
        var _tileLayer = new HttpMapTileDataSource();
        _tileLayer.UriFormatString = IcaoUri;
        _icaoTileSource.DataSource = _tileLayer;
        MyMap.TileSources.Add(_icaoTileSource);

        //Setup VFR Layer
        _vfrTileSource = new MapTileSource();
        var _vfrtileLayer = new HttpMapTileDataSource();
        _vfrtileLayer.UriFormatString = VfrUri;
        _vfrTileSource.DataSource = _vfrtileLayer;

        //Setup Low Level Layer
        _lowlvlTileSource = new MapTileSource();
        var _lowlvltileLayer = new HttpMapTileDataSource();
        _lowlvltileLayer.UriFormatString = LowLvlUri;
        _lowlvlTileSource.DataSource = _lowlvltileLayer;

        airplane = new MapIcon()
        {
            Title = "My Position",
            Image = image,
            Visible = true,
            Location = cologne,
            NormalizedAnchorPoint = new Point(0.5, 0.5)

        };
        _tileLayer.AllowCaching = true;
        MyMap.MapElements.Add(airplane);
        systemSetCenter = true;
        MyMap.Center = cologne;
        MyMap.ZoomLevel = 10;
        _vm.ZoomLevel = MyMap.ZoomLevel;
        MyMap.ZoomLevelChanged += (s, e) =>
        {
            if(s.ZoomLevel > maxZoomLevel)
            {
                s.ZoomLevel = maxZoomLevel;
            }
            _vm.ZoomLevel = s.ZoomLevel;
        };
    }
```